# Deleting specific intervals of rows in a csv file with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks to some nice guys here at this forum, I have been able to use the following macro for something I need :

```
Public Sub main()
    'declaration
    Dim rng As Range
    Const SourceRange = "H"
    Dim NumRange As Range, formulaCell As Range
    Dim SumAddr As String
    Dim c As Long

    'Loop trough all rows
    Set rng = Range("H2")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        rng.Offset(20).Resize(1).EntireRow.Insert
        Set rng = rng.Offset(21)
    Wend

   'Fill the Blank Rows in A
   Columns("A:A").Select
   Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
   Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"


   For Each NumRange In Columns(SourceRange).SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas
       SumAddr = NumRange.Address(False, False)
       Set formulaCell = NumRange.Offset(NumRange.Count, 0).Resize(1, 1)
       formulaCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & SumAddr & ")"

       'change formatting to your liking:
       formulaCell.Font.Bold = True
       formulaCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       c = NumRange.Count
   Next NumRange

End Sub
```

In short, this creates a row every 20th row, takes the number from the cell above in column "A" in the blank row and sum up the 20th previous cells in column "H" to put a "total score" in the blank row.

I have one more question regarding this macro.

After having run the macro above, the "Sum" of 20 and 20 rows is placed in the new row added. Ideally, I would like to delete all of the 20 rows that have been summed and just have the added row left. The problem with this is the last part of the previous macro sums a given number of cells up, and if I delete the rows the summing will be wrong (as well as the number from the cell above in column A).

Is there any way to add something to the macro so that it deletes 20 and rows without effecting the summing and the number from the previous cell in column A?

It would look something like this: Delete rows 2-21, skip row 22, delete row 23-42, skip row 43, delete row 44-63, skip row 64 and so on.

I understand that this probably means having to alter the previous macro posted, but I guess it's worth asking.

Thanks in advance guys.

Best, Helge

Comment: So basically, you want to change `formulaCell` from a formula to a value so it will not change, and you want to delete the rows that you were summing up in that formula, correct?

Comment: That is correct! Additionally, I want to make the number from the cell above in collumn A constant as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Public Sub main()
    'declaration
    Dim rng As Range
    Const SourceRange = "H"
    Dim NumRange As Range, formulaCell As Range
    Dim SumAddr As String
    Dim c As Long
    Dim iFirstRow As Integer, iLastCell As Integer


    'Loop trough all rows in H column
    Set rng = Range(SourceRange & "2")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        rng.Offset(20).Resize(1).EntireRow.Insert
        With rng.Offset(20)
            .Formula = "=sum(" & SourceRange & rng.Row & ":" & SourceRange & rng.Offset(19).Row & ")"
            .Formula = .Value2

           'change formatting to your liking:
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

            'set next group start
            Set rng = rng.Offset(21)

            'delete rows
            iFirstRow = .Column - 1
            With Range(.Offset(-20, -iFirstRow), .Offset(-1, -iFirstRow))

                iLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                'Fill the Blank Rows in A
                With Cells(rng.Offset(-1).Row, 1)
                    .Formula = "=" & Cells(iLastCell, 1).Address
                    .Formula = .Value2
                End With

                'Delete group rows
                .EntireRow.Delete
            End With

        End With
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is beautiful. There is one "problem" left, however. The 'Fill the Blank Rows in A does not "keep" the information it had when the rows are deleted.I am trying to see from your code where you make "sum" ("H") constant even after deleting all other rows, but I cannot find it.

Comment: I didn´t quite understand what you want in the A column. Please explain in detail. To remove the function but keep the values, use `.Formula = .Value2` for your cell.

Comment: You are exactly right; I would like to remove the function in collumn A, but keep the values. The  .Formula = .Value2 is written in the 'Fill the Blank Rows in A, however, when I run the macro it still takes the information from the previous cell. As an example: Collumn A is named "Candidate". When I run the macro A2, A3, A4, A5, A6 is first filled with candidate numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but when the macro deletes the rows A2, A3, A4, A5 and A6 takes the information from the cell above which is then "Candidate". Does this makes sense? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ok so you want the result to be "Candidate" in cell A and the sum in cell H ?

Comment: No, the result is "Candidate" as it stands now. I want the macro to take the information from the cell above the blank cell (before the rows are deleted) in collumn "A", f.ex. "5" and then keep this value after the rows have been deleted. Does this make sense to you? I'm sorry if I am being unclear. The sum part is working beautifully.

Comment: So all you want is a number that counts how many candidates you had?

Comment: No :)    The macro does four things:
1. Create a new row every 20th row
2.Take the number from the cell above (collumn A) and fill the blank space in the new row with this number.
3. Sum the numbers in collumn H from the 20 rows before the new row to get a total score. This is done subsequently for as long as new rows appear (every 20th row). 4. Delete all the rows that have been summed in 3. so that you only have the newly created row left. The problem is that when all rows are deleted the information in collumn A is changed from the number it had to "Candidate" in all the rows.

Comment: So if you have 1,2,3,4,5, blank, blank, blank...  in A column, you want the new row´s A cell to be 5 ?

Comment: Please create an example of your input and desired output and post pictures of both of them. The explanation is very confusing.

Comment: Will do, mate! Don't have time now, but I will get back to it as soon as I can.